# Apache CXF interceptor in JAX-WS webservice not invoking

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, interceptor

I want to get SOAP incoming request body in my webservice when it is invoked. To do this I created a JAX-WS web service and used annotation to create an apache CXF interceptor, but when I invoke web service with SOAPUI, my web service directly run instead of going in interceptor. Code would be like

```
@org.apache.cxf.interceptor.InInterceptors (interceptors =          {"./BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor" })

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://com.services", serviceName =  "MyService", portName = "myPort")
public class MyServiceJax
{
}
```

the code for interceptor is

```
public class BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor extends
AbstractSoapInterceptor {

public BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor() {
super(Phase.RECEIVE);
}
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {

List <Header> list = message.getHeaders();
for (Header header : list) {
System.out.println(header.getName() + " = " + header.toString());
}
}
}
```

Is there any other configuration I have to add ? I do not have CXF.XML file created as I wanted to use annotation.

Regards,

Aiden

Comment: Try giving the complete package name of the BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor class in @org.apache.cxf.interceptor.InInterceptors instead of ./ ?

Comment: Will try...thanks....but there is no other configuration entry beside just adding @ annotation and putting the cxf jar in build path ?

Comment: No. For programmatic configuration, that should suffice I believe(http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html). Try if that works with complete package name. If so, will post it as answer for you.

Comment: Thanks! tried but it won't pick :( I believe the reason is that my web-service is not CXF based web service but simple jax-ws, I think to make it work, service has to be published with CXF e.g. using web.xml – and putting in cxf-servlet e.g. here http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/apache-cxf-jax-ws-simple-tutorial.html. I think I should mark this question as answered then

Comment: Lol. It was never a cxf based? For sure wont work then :D The interceptors are CXF's interceptors that are registered as cxf:bus interceptors :) Okie then.

Comment: hehehhe sorry :) just novice :)